# append dataframe to an existing excel file with keeping a vba

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xlsxwriter, xlwings

```
import xlwings as xw
file_path = './DD_Template.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Citation'

start_row = 2

wb = xw.Book(file_path)
sheet = wb.sheets[sheet_name]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='xlsxwriter',mode='a')

df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet_name,startrow=start_row,index=False)
wb.close()
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

no error in code but while opening a excel file getting an pop up message escel find unreachable content.
please help.

Comment: Is it a part of some bigger code? I can't see what's the use of `xlwings` here. What if you remove the lines where `xlwings` is used only to open and close the document, does it help?

Comment: The whole code sample really doesn't make sense. These days you should use a Context Manager for your writer.